# ios 9 UITableView freezes when deleting cell and does not show confirmation title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

I have a code written in `Objective-C` for deleting `cells` from `tableview`.

Here's the code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == (self.numberOfAddsShowing - 1) && (*moreAvailable)) {
    return NO;
  }

  if (isEditable) {
    return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return @"حذف";
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
     forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    NSInteger rowNumber = indexPath.row;

    if (rowNumber >= self.addsToShow.count) {
      return;
    }

    HJAdd *adToDelete = [self.addsToShow objectAtIndex:rowNumber];

    if (!self.adsToDelete) {
      self.adsToDelete = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [self.adsToDelete
        addObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:adToDelete.addId] stringValue]];

    [self.addsToShow removeObjectAtIndex:rowNumber];

      [tableView beginUpdates];
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ indexPath ]
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [tableView endUpdates];

  }

  [self setEditButtonState];
}
```

The problem is that when I enter edit mode and try deleting the `cell`, the confirmation title is not shown and I am unable to delete the cell. When I finish  editing mode, the `UITableView` is no longer scrollable. Swipe to delete is also not working. When I swipe, the `tableView` enters edit mode but I cannot see the delete button.

When I run the app in Simulator with `iOS 8.1` or lower, its working fine.

[Here's](https://youtu.be/_ChZoiyIgTA) a video I uploaded to Youtube to show the problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks to all!

Comment: Is there an error message showing up in the console after a while ? Does your CPU usage increase ?

Comment: You're probably stuck in an infinite loop on one of your methods. Try setting up break points throughout your code like in the `canEditCellForRowAtIndexPath` and such methods if it's hard to find.

Comment: @Randy there are no error messages in console. The CPU usage stays at 0%. If I try scrolling it goes upto 5%.

Comment: @Scott I have set breakpoints to those methods and they're getting called when scrolling the tableView. When cell loading is finished, they're not called anymore. titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath is also getting called but not shown. It works fine on iOS 8 simulator.

Comment: @AbdullahUmer Strange. Well try reseting your device. Cleaning the build and reinstalling your app on the device. If you've done that then some method is being called that's causing this. Try setting breakpoints on the top of all your methods in the view controller class and whatever classes you might be using and activate them just before you start to delete. Also if that doesn't work try overwriting superclass methods like scrollViewWillBeginDragging: and the such and don't forget to call their super as well.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the suggestions but They did not help. How odd that the code is working fine in iOS 8 simulator :(

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 8.1 or lower device? Only simulator?

Comment: I haven't tried on device with iOS 8.1 or lower. The app target is iOS 7.1 and so far no user has complained about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];`.

I think these are for code outside of the commitEditingStyle method.

In the [TableView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) these are not used.

Comment: that code has no effect. commitEditingStyle is never getting called any way :(

Comment: and my code is working fine in iOS 8.1. It's only iOS 9 where something got changed and my code doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. Is your data source set? CommitEditingStyle is a data source method.

Comment: Yes, of course it's set. How would it load the cells :D

Answer (score 0):

if you have a button bar Item

```
ViewDidload
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;



- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   TableAccountViewCell *accountCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if ([accountCell.myLabel.text isEqualToString:ADD_USER])
   {
       return NO;
   }

    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}   


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [menuItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    //
    // Start SQL Delele Account.
    //


    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately your code is not helpful. In my case the confirmation delete button does not show up and hence commitEditingStyle: is never called. Please watch the video I posted the link in question. Thanks!